# Changing color of table row by a class in tr

Tags: html, css

I want to change the background color of all td in a tr just using a class in the tr. I am using the following css

```
tr .yellow td{
background-color: yellow;
```

}

And I have following html

```
<tr class="yellow"><td></td> <td></td></tr>
```

But the background color is not changing. What is the mistake here?

Comment: remove the space between tr and .yellow. So tr.yellow

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have a **space** before the class in your CSS declaration

```
tr.yellow td{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

You need to remove the space to indicate that the class is on the `<tr>` element. Without it you are suggesting that the hierarchy is:

> tr, then something with a class of "yellow", then a td

e.g.

```
<tr>
  <sometag class="yellow">
    <td>
```

Which *isn't* what your DOM looks like.